# How do I make a live search result in node.js and mongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to implement a feature where I have an input on this route to make a live search of employees in the database

```
app.get('/delete' , isLoggedIn , (req , res) => {
    res.render('pages/delete')
})
```

This route serves the search input. How do I create a live search based on a keyup event listener that sends the data to mongoDb/mongoose to search and return the results on the page?

I know how to do the event listener to get what is typed like so which is in the delete.js file

```
const deleteSearchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');

deleteSearchInput.addEventListener('keyup' , (e) => {
    let search = e.target.value.trim()
})
```

How do I send the value "e" to a post route to do the search and return it to the page

Comment: Post route or Get route?

Comment: I want it to be a post route since it will be doing some queries. The get route was just to bring or render the form @code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX (using the JavaScript `fetch` API). AJAX allows JavaScript to send requests to the server without reloading.

```js
const deleteSearchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');

deleteSearchInput.addEventListener('keyup' , (e) => {
    let search = e.target.value.trim();
    fetch('/delete', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({search})
    }).then(res =>
        res.json()
    ).then(data => {
        console.log(data.result); // <-- success!
    }).catch(err => {
        alert('error!');
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Then you have changes to make to the server side. Since you're sending a POST request, you need to create a handler to POST:

```js
app.post('/delete', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.send('success!');
});
```

This will handle post requests, and only post requests. Now to get the value of whatever you sent to the server, we need to use an npm package called body-parser, which parses the incoming request. Run the following command in shell:

```sh
npm i body-parser
```

Then at the top of your server file before declaring your routes import and use the body-parser library:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // <-- add the JSON parser
```

Finally change your handler again:

```js
app.post('/delete', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    const { search } = req.body;
    console.log(search);
    // ... do whatever you want and send a response, e.g.:
    const result = 'my awesome message';
    res.json({ result });
});
```

And that's how you do it.